# Does deploying an Azure function that uses a customer handler require a docker image per function?

Tags: azure-functions

It looks like the only way to make use of a custom handler for an Azure function is to use a docker image deployment, which means that I have to build a dedicated docker image to contain my function.
Naively I assumed I'd be able to do a zip deployment, but specify a custom base image in which to run it. This would then contain my custom azure function runtime, set up to serve the function in much the same way that a standard Azure function works.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you require a custom language runtime that isn't already present in the App Service Environment, a custom container isn't necessary as [mentioned in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers#deploying).

You would simply have to [configure `host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers#configuration) with both an executable (node, java, etc.) and the path to the worker. But for all other scenarios, you would have to [build your own container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp).